# unit testing custom OnRender-Method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control `MyControl` which inherits from `Canvas` and which has its own logic inside the `OnRender`-Method.
It should draw some rectangles and text into the drawing context.

```
public class MyControl : Canvas
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        // do something like dc.DrawRectangle(...);
        // do something like dc.DrawText(...);
    }
}
```

Since I have to develop test-driven, I want to unit test the `OnRender`-Method.
I tried several solutions which did not work. All of them required an inherited class for testing purpose, which I will call `TestingMyControl` and which exposes the `OnRender`-Method in the follwing form:

```
public class TestingMyControl : MyControl
{
    public void Render(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
}
```

1. Since `DrawingContext` is an abstract class, I thought I could implement a test class which implements `DrawingContext`. I could then collect all the rectangles and text which it should draw, and make assertions against this. **Problem**: `DrawingContext` has an internal constructor, so I cannot inherit from it.
2. Since `DrawingContext` is an abstract class, I thought I could create a Mock of it. 
   **Problem**: it has some internal abstract Methods, so Rhino-Mocks could not create a proxy, since it cannot implement these internal abstract Methods.

So I have the problem, that I cannot test the OnRender-Method, since I cannot create an Instance of `DrawingContext`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is, to create the `DrawingContext` out of an `DrawingGroup`.

```
public class TestingMyControl : MyControl
{
    public DrawingGroup Render()
    {
        var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
        using (var drawingContext = drawingGroup.Open())
        {
             base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        }

        return drawingGroup;
    }
}
```

So the fixture will look like:

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_render()
    {
        var controlToTest = new TestingMyControl();

        var drawingGroup = controlToTest.Render();

        var drawing = drawingGroup.Children[0] as GeometryDrawing;
        Assert.That(drawing.Brush, Is.EqualTo(Brushes.Black));
        Assert.That(drawing.Pen.Brush, Is.EqualTo(Brushes.SeaGreen));
        Assert.That(drawing.Pen.Thickness, Is.EqualTo(0.6));
        Assert.That(drawing.Bounds.X, Is.EqualTo(5));
        Assert.That(drawing.Bounds.Y, Is.EqualTo(15));
        Assert.That(drawing.Bounds.Width, Is.EqualTo(25));
        Assert.That(drawing.Bounds.Height, Is.EqualTo(35));
    }
```

This requires the follwing production code:

```
public class MyControl : Canvas
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Pen(Brushes.SeaGreen, 0.6), new Rect(5, 15, 25, 35));
    }
}
```